# Remote shutdown of Dell PowerVault MD3000

Tags: ups, electrical-power, remote-access, dell-powervault

It's heating up down here (Australia) and we always have power issues over the summer at one of our sites.

We have a [reasonable UPS](http://powerquality.eaton.com/Products-services/Backup-Power-UPS/9155.aspx) with massive batteries and run an agent on our Servers that shuts them down after a specific period, but I'm wondering how/if we can do it with our MD3000.

I suppose, I'm also wondering if it's necessary to worry about it? I don't like the idea of sudden power loss to the array, but that may not be warranted. I'd be surprised if that were the case though.

It's a new piece of kit for us, and has only been in production for a few months.

Is it possible to shut it down gracefully in the event of power failure? If so, how can we do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, the MD3000 has no ability to perform a graceful shutdown (there are no reboot or power commands that I'm aware of). It shuts down when the host server shuts down. If you have your servers configured to perform a graceful shutdown, that should be enough for the MD3000.

Also, here's a link to the MD3000 CLI reference:

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/md3000/en/CLI/PDF/CLIA00MR.pdf

Comment: Happy to help..